# How to get data in AutoCompleteTextView using mysql database?

Tags: android, mysql, autocompletetextview

I used the demo from android tutorials but it generating the error like

```
    Error:(116, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable menu
Note: C:\Users\sachin\Desktop\AddVisit\app\src\main\java\com\example\sachin\addvisit\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

the complete code as follow:

**Mainactivity.java**

```
    package com.example.sachin.addvisit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/portal/autocomplete.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("Pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json= null;
            final String[] str1 = new String[JA.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
                str1[i]=json.getString("name");
            }

            final AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
            final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i<str1.length;i++)
            {
                list.add(str1[i]);
            }

            Collections.sort(list);

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            text.setThreshold(1);
            text.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            text.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), list.get(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:ems="13"
    android:hint="AutoCompleteTextView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to get a suggestion from the database in my **AutoCompleteTextview** I tried a lot but its not working at all.
[please refer this link i tried this demo](http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/07/autocompletetextview.html)

**Logcat**

```
   10-01 10:14:04.119 2921-2921/com.example.sachin.addvisit E/Fail 1: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-01 10:14:04.152 2921-2921/com.example.sachin.addvisit E/Fail 2: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
10-01 10:14:04.153 2921-2921/com.example.sachin.addvisit E/Fail 3: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is from this method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Error is `cannot find symbol variable menu` and cause is `uses or overrides a deprecated API.`

You are probably using an older version of the appcompat library. Reference the new version of appcompat in build.gradle.

**Updated**

According to the updated question, you are getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. To overcome this problem, Run your code in [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Also add this to `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'

Comment: what should i do for solving this?

Comment: @user6880336 You can remove `onCreateOptionsMenu` method if you don't need an `OptionsMenu`

Comment: i did it but not getting the suggestion from the database.

Comment: when i run the application the toast print "invalid ip"

Comment: Please help me out from this sir,,

Comment: @user6880336 What is the `e.toString()` prints with `Fail 1`?

Comment: @user6880336 Can you access `http://10.0.2.2/portal/autocomplete.php` via web browser?

Comment: yes... getting this output [{"0":"1","roll no":"1","1":"aaaa","name":"aaaa"},{"0":"2","roll no":"2","1":"aaa","name":"aaa"},{"0":"11111111","roll no":"11111111","1":"sachin","name":"sachin"},{"0":"2222222","roll no":"2222222","1":"sachinsss","name":"sachinsss"}]

Comment: @user6880336 Ok. Then what is the `e.toString()` prints with `Fail 1`?

Comment: actually i pasted the same code from this link http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/07/autocompletetextview.html

Comment: so i really don't know .. and three of this are returning null

Comment: http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/07/autocompletetextview-from-database.html?view=sidebar

Comment: ok ill try this and i already didthis...<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: i tried but it is generating errors.. can yo please explain me with the code

Comment: i Tried now its working but the thing is the color of dropdown list is white so how can i change color of it?

Comment: @user6880336 Use `android:popupBackground="ffff00"` in your `AutoCompleteTextView` in **activity_main**

Comment: i did the same but generating error like Error:(15, 30) String types not allowed (at 'popupBackground' with value 'ffff00').

Comment: its working but i want to change the color of font not background

Comment: @user6880336 Sorry . It should be `#ffff00`. btw to change the font color, use `android:textColor="#ffff00"`

Comment: Now it is working perfectly... for change color i create a my_list.xml file in that i used textview  and i apply  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.my_list.xml,list); here i set color

Comment: i get another problem on it... when i set the toast on onItemclickListner it will displaying another data..

Comment: like if i select first item it will toast "first item" and when i select any other item it displays "first item " only in Toast